# input id reserved word

Tags: javascript, html

I was about to answer a question here and found my self struggling with what seemed to be an easy thing to understand.
Consider this HTML:

```html
<input type="text" id="width" value="foo" />
<input type="button" value="width.value" onclick="console.log(width.value)"/>
<input type="button" value="window.width.value" onclick="console.log(window.width.value)"/>
```

We have an `input` with an `id` of `width` and two buttons that has an `onClick` event that all it does is logging the input's value. The different between them is that one input accessing the input's id as a variable directly `width.value` and the other one is doing it via `window.width.value`.
The amazing part here is that only the `window.width.value` works and the other one returns `undefined`.

I've looked up javascript reserved key words but couldn't find anything about `width`, By the way it is the same with the `height` key word as well.
What am i missing?

Comment: This is all about scope. In your `width.value` you're accessing the button's width-attribute. `width.value == this.width.value` in this case.

Comment: Just about to say what @FrederikHansen said, your basically forgetting that INPUT's have attributes too,.. like width & height..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onclick` method is being called on the `button` objects.  Therefore, unless you specify that you want the window's `width` property, it will be shadowed by the button object's `width` property.  In this case, the button's width doesn't have a `value` property.

Comment: i can't believe i forgot about that! :)